# Two forms, one php script - success message echoed beneath form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two forms on a single PHP page.  The first asking for an email and the second asking for feedback.  Both forms are named differently and work.  I have the php script working and results going to two different databases so all good there.

The problem arises when I want a confirmation message to appear just beneath each form. At the moment the confirmation messages appear at the top of the page when a user clicks the 'Subscribe' or 'Post Feedback' buttons.  How can I get each confirmation message to appear just beneath the forms (indicated by the HTML comment tags in the form code below)?

I am sure there is a relatively straightforward way of doing this, but I just don't see it.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['submit'] == 'Subscribe'){
        //process form1


        $email = str_replace("'", "\'", htmlentities($_POST['email']));


        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'newslist') 
        or die('Error no connection to server.');


        $query = "INSERT INTO email_list(email, submitted) VALUES ('$email', now())";


        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');


        mysqli_close($dbc);

        echo "<p span style=\"color:#c3593c; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;  text-align:center\">Thanks for signing up.</span></p>";

    }


        else if($_POST['submit'] == 'Post Feedback'){
        //process form2


        $feedback = str_replace("'", "\'", htmlentities($_POST['feedback']));


        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'feedbacklist') 
        or die('Error no connection to server.');


        $query = "INSERT INTO feedback(feedback, submitted) VALUES ('$feedback', now())";


        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');


        mysqli_close($dbc);

        echo "<p span style=\"color:#c3593c; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; text-align:center\">Thanks for the feedback.</span></p>";
    }
}
?>



<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#newsletter, #feedback{
    padding: 15px;
background-color: #E4E4E4;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 300px;}

#newsletter h2, #feedback h2{
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #c3593c;
    font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;}

#newsletter p, #feedback p{
    font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="newsletter">
<h2>Newsletter</h2>
<p>Subscribe to our newsletter.</p><br />
<form name="mailinglist" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<p><strong>Email</strong> <input type="text" name="email" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></p>
<!--I want the first message echoed here once & only if the first form has been submitted-->
</form>
</div>


<br /><br />


<div id="feedback">
<h2>Feedback</h2>
<p>Post your feedback.</p><br />
<form name="feedback" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<p>Your Suggestion:<br /><textarea name="feedback" rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Post Feedback" /></p>
<!--I want the second message echoed here once & only if the second form has been submitted-->
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Andy ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code, I would do it like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Subscribe'){
    //process form1


    $email = str_replace("'", "\'", htmlentities($_POST['email']));


    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'newslist') 
    or die('Error no connection to server.');


    $query = "INSERT INTO email_list(email, submitted) VALUES ('$email', now())";


    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');


    mysqli_close($dbc);

    $subscribe_message = "<p span style=\"color:#c3593c; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;  text-align:center\">Thanks for signing up.</span></p>";

}


    else if($_POST['submit'] == 'Post Feedback'){
    //process form2


    $feedback = str_replace("'", "\'", htmlentities($_POST['feedback']));


    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'feedbacklist') 
    or die('Error no connection to server.');


    $query = "INSERT INTO feedback(feedback, submitted) VALUES ('$feedback', now())";


    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');


    mysqli_close($dbc);

    $feedback_message = "<p span style=\"color:#c3593c; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; text-align:center\">Thanks for the feedback.</span></p>";
}
}
?>



<html>

...

<body>

<div id="newsletter">
<h2>Newsletter</h2>
<p>Subscribe to our newsletter.</p><br />
<form name="mailinglist" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<p><strong>Email</strong> <input type="text" name="email" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></p>
<!--I want the first message echoed here once & only if the first form has been submitted-->
<? echo $subscribe_message; ?>
</form>
</div>


<br /><br />


<div id="feedback">
<h2>Feedback</h2>
<p>Post your feedback.</p><br />
<form name="feedback" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<p>Your Suggestion:<br /><textarea name="feedback" rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Post Feedback" /></p>
<!--I want the second message echoed here once & only if the second form has been submitted-->
<? echo $feedback_message?>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Borko. The messages show correctly. Thanks very much. Unfortunately what happens now is the following error messages:
When I fill in the feedback box I get this appearing at the subscribe email field:

Notice: Undefined variable: subscribe_message in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\newsletter.php on line 106


When I fill in the subscribe email field I get this appearing at the feedback box:

Notice: Undefined variable: idea_message in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\newsletter.php on line 120

Any ideas?  I'm not sure why this is happening. Thanks for your help.

Andy :-)

Comment: Yes ;-) Got it.  I see what was wrong now.  I never declared the variables you recommended using at the top of the script.  All working now.  Thanks Borko ;-)

Comment: Yeah, glad you got it working... Maybe it's not good, but I personally never look back when php gives me the "Notice" :P

Answer (score 1):

Consider splitting the existing PHP code into two parts.

```
<form name="mailinglist" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<p><strong>Email</strong> <input type="text" name="email" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></p>
<!--I want the first message echoed here once & only if the first form has been submitted-->
</form>

Put the first one here:
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if($_POST['submit'] == 'Subscribe'){
// do stuff
}
}?>

<form name="feedback" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<p>Your Suggestion:<br /><textarea name="feedback" rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Post Feedback" /></p>
<!--I want the second message echoed here once & only if the second form has been submitted-->
</form>

    Put the second one here:
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['submit'] == 'feedback'){
    // do stuff
    }
    }?>
```

Comment: Hi Sasanka.  This isn't working for me, but thanks for the suggestion. I still don't see what I am doing wrong.  Perhaps another break from it and with a fresh outlook I will see it. Thanks for your help. Andy ;-)

Comment: Can you elaborate why it isn't working and what exactly happens?